# Printing Array on seperate lines

Tags: python, arrays, list, printing

I have a list that contains the following data.

```
1/3/2015
4
18
43
46
55
25
3
12/30/2015
12 
36 
38 
54 
61 
22 
3
```

I am trying to get the series of numbers to print one line. I have tried `print(" ".join(series[0:8]))` and it only prints the last line like this

12/31/2016 1 3 28 57 67 9 2

12/28/2016 16 23 30 44 58 4 2

Does anyone have a way to print both lines?

Should I use a loop to accomplish what I am looking for?

Comment: Can you clarify your list definition? Is it `series = ['1/3/2015', 4, 18, 43, 46, 55, 25, 3, '12/30/2015', 12, 36, 38, 54, 61, 22, 3]`? Or something else?

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: I want the list to print out two seperate lines
12/30/2015 12 36 38 54 61 22 3
12/26/2015 27 40 44 59 65 20 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "one-line" you just want everything on one line, then remove the [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice) operation.

```
print(" ".join(series))
#Out> 1/3/2015 4 18 43 46 55 25 3 12/30/2015 12 36 38 54 61 22 3
```

However, if you know that all your items have the same length and you want them on different lines:

```
for i in range(0, len(series), 8):
    print(" ".join(series[i:i+8]))
#Out> 1/3/2015 4 18 43 46 55 25 3
#Out> 12/30/2015 12 36 38 54 61 22 3
```

The above uses the `step` parameter of the [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) function to skip over 8 elements. And the slice only uses that section to print them on separate lines.

The following makes use of list comprehension to get your chunks and accomplish the same as above:

```
for section in (series[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(series), 8)):
    print(" ".join(section))
#Out> 1/3/2015 4 18 43 46 55 25 3
#Out> 12/30/2015 12 36 38 54 61 22 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a for-loop, you can just make two `print` calls:

```
print(' '.join(series[0:8]))
print(' '.join(series[8:16]))
```

Comment: Thank you  that works. I am trying to learn this language doing small projects.  I try to wait until I am stuck before asking questions.

Comment: Did OP specifically mention that his data was swapped, and without quotes as you edited his post?